は vs が in the following sentence
田中の判断を理解できない者が数多くいた
田中の判断を理解できない者は数多くいた
I understand the differences between は and が in most sentences, but sometimes sentences come like this and confuse me. In this case, I just can't get the nuance/ when you would use one over the other.
Is my interpretation below correct here?
田中の判断を理解できない者は数多くいた
(There were many people who couldn’t understand Tanaka’s decision, and that’s just a general fact. No special focus on who they are.)
田中の判断を理解できない者が数多くいた
(There were many people who couldn’t understand Tanaka’s decision, and I’m emphasizing the fact that these people specifically didn’t understand. It’s more surprising or notable as if saying "Can you believe there were so many who didn’t get it?")

Maybe this question helps? https://ja.hinative.com/questions/17906879

No, the link that you sent has a really simple nuance that I already understand(contrasting wa). It's just that it's not so simple in the sentence that I provided.

Are you still looking for something other than what's in the answer(s)? The system will solicit more answers until you accept one answer.

Sorry, just chose your answer.

I know this will sounds like a non-answer, but it depends on context, specifically, which part has been known to the reader, which part is going to be contrasted. It can be the old information vs new information difference, or contrastive は and neutral が.
If you add one or two sentences before and after, we can more clearly say which interpretation would be correct.
Here are some examples.
が for new information:

A 田中の判断には複雑な理由があった。田中の判断を理解できない者は多くいた。だから合意は得られなかった。
B 田中の判断には複雑な理由があった。田中の判断を理解できない者が多くいた。だから合意は得られなかった。

In A, the second sentence sounds like a continuation of the first sentence - or it acknowledges that many people not understanding it is old information in some sense. In B, the first and second sentences sound like presenting evidence one by one independently. Both are grammatically fine and mean something similar, but the information structure is a bit different.
は for contrast:

C 田中の判断を理解できない者は多くいた。佐藤の判断を理解できない者はもっと多くいた。 -- okay
D 田中の判断を理解できない者が多くいた。佐藤の判断を理解できない者がもっと多くいた。 -- questionable (but it depends on what comes next)

C is how you normally structure a contrast. I don't think D is ungrammatical, but a proofreader might want to correct it if it's meant to be a simple contrast.
Obviously, these are not an exhaustive list. But I feel like the qustion as it is written is too open-ended to cover all possibilities.

Can you please add some context to the sentences and demonstrate which would be correct for each case?

I've added some.

Thank you for the explanation. Just one thing I want to confirm: In case of A, if  "田中の判断を理解できない者" was implied from context before like in the first part of the sentence:
"田中の判断には複雑な理由があった" (even though, it doesn't directly imply it, it says that it's complicated which could lead the listener to think that maybe many people didn't understand that decision)  you would use は、and if it was new information, you would use が？

Basically yes, but in the example I wrote, it's more like the author presenting it as new than it being new objectively.

I see. So if something is implied through context(directly or indirectly) you'd normally use は, and as for new information が.
